# SQL: To search values in a table without a '@' character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried :

```
Use SchoolDB

Select Distinct Surnames from Students
where Surname LIKE '%^@%'
```

above I get zero values.

I also tried replacing `'%^@%'` with `'%[!@]%'` or `'%[^@]%'`

Comment: `NOT LIKE '%@%'` sounds like what you want.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
DISTINCT Surnames 
FROM Students
WHERE 
Surname NOT LIKE '%@%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use NOT LIKE, like this:

```
where Surname NOT LIKE '%[@]%'
```

Expect it helps.